# I want to know how many Switch is enable at same time and print Their Values

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know how many Switch is enable at same time and print Their Values
in Toast, How can i do it

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.Switch;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class ListItem extends AppCompatActivity {


        Switch s1,s2,s3,s4;
        int Switch;

        Switch[] switches = new Switch[]{s1,s2,s3,s4};
        Button submit;



        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);

            s1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            s2 = findViewById(R.id.switch2);
            s3 = findViewById(R.id.switch3);
            s4 = findViewById(R.id.switch4);
            submit = findViewById(R.id.clickbtn);


            s1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    if (isChecked == true) {


                        String result1 = "Table";







                    }
                }
            });


            s2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    if (isChecked == true) {

                        String result1 = "Chair";






                    }
                }
            });


            s3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    if (isChecked == true) {

                        String result1 = "Laptop";



                    }
                }
            });


            s4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {


                    if (isChecked == true) {

                        String result1 = "Desktop";






                    }
                }
            });



            submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    for (int i = 1; i <= switches.length; i++) {
                        s








                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You picked Table and chair", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                }





            });







        }

 }
```

I have a list of some item if user checked three switches Then  user Got A Toast message with value like you checked Three item, please find the code i am trying but i have only static method to check these possibility.

Comment: try using separate string variable for each of the switch and set and clear their values when your switch turns on or off. now when you want to show toast concatenate those strings and use them

Answer (score 1):

No need for setOnCheckedChange listener. Try this. Or customize it however you want

```
            s1 = findViewById(R.id.switch1);
            s2 = findViewById(R.id.switch2);
            s3 = findViewById(R.id.switch3);
            s4 = findViewById(R.id.switch4);

            s1.setTag("Table1");
            s2.setTag("Table2");
            s3.setTag("Table3");
            s4.setTag("Table4");
 submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

               String ss = "You picked ";
               for (Switch s: switches) {
                     if(s.isChecked())
                       ss+=s.getTag() + ", " ;



               }

              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ss, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is check the 3 switches status on the `onClickListener` of the submit `Button`. If the switch is already `isChecked`, then include it's text on a string for the Toast. You're already doing it. Just continue your code.

Comment: Actually i need , if i checked 3 switch then a toast message is with these 3 value, and if i checked 2, 1 or none they return Toast message with values

Comment: So, you mean, you want to display a `Toast` every time you check a `Switch`?

Comment: Yes but not every if i switched  3 Item at same time then Toast return A message with 3 item values

Comment: Then follow my answer. That's how you should do it.

Comment: i am waiting for your ans

Comment: It's already above this comments. Are you expecting a code answer? At least figure it out from my answer.